# Issue while creating workspace in perforce

Tags: perforce

I am not able to create a workspace in perforce. I go to Connection --> New Workspace and then give desired workspace name and workspaceroot and then click "OK". And also it does not give any error. But when I try to access the workspace to add files in it,I am not able to access it, it gives error as "the path is not found". This means workspace has not been created in my local system. Can you please help here? I am new to perforce so please answer accordingly.

Comment: Have you had a look at the "Getting Started" manuals here: http://www.perforce.com/documentation/perforce_technical_documentation

Comment: It would help if you posting specific error messages, and what values you are using for your client settings.  A message about a path not found could be a client problem, but it could also be a server problem depending on the command that you ran.  Unlikely, but hard to know unless we can get some more specifics.

Answer (score 3):

In perforce a workspace (aka client) defines the mapping of depot files to the files in your workspace (this is called the "clientview").

Most probably you made a mistake in your client view or when adding the files so that they don't fit (e.g. you can't add a file to perforce when the client does not contain a mapping for the local path it is located to a location in the depot).

In order to give better advice you need to post the content your client and the path of the files you want to add.